# odoo how to set selected attribute in website-template

Tags: forms, select, odoo

I have a bit of trouble in Odoo, setting the selected attribute for a website-formular.

I have some data in an underlying model, which is displayed in a table inside the form. The lines are displayed correctly, but the values for the select-field are not set correctly. It always shows the first value in the select-list instead the saved value in the model.

```python
    <t t-foreach="quote_lines" t-as="quote_line">               
    <tr>
       <td>
          <!--  public categories for a selection field -->
          <select t-attf-name="supplier_{{quote_line.line}}">
             <t t-foreach="categories" t-as="c">
                <t t-if="c.name==quote_line.supplier"><option t-field="c.name" selected="selected" /></t>
                <t t-if="c.name!=quote_line.supplier"><option t-field="c.name" /></t>
             </t>
          </select>
        </td>
        ....
    </tr>
    </t>
```

The form is loaded into odoo and displays fine - except that the -tag ignores my selected attribute. When i look in the generated html, the select/option values are set, just this attribute is ignored.

Any hints what i'm doing wrong or just don't see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `selected="True"`

Also, take a look at how **website_sale** does for countries:

```
              <div t-attf-class="form-group #{error.get('shipping_country_id') and 'has-error' or ''} col-lg-6">
                  <label class="control-label" for="shipping_country_id">Country</label>
                  <select name="shipping_country_id" class="form-control" t-att-disabled="  'disabled' if shipping_id &gt;= 0 else ''">
                      <option value="">Country...</option>
                      <t t-foreach="countries or []" t-as="country">
                          <option t-att-value="country.id" t-att-selected="country.id == checkout.get('shipping_country_id')"><t t-esc="country.name"/></option>
                      </t>
                  </select>
              </div>
```

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/website_sale/views/templates.xml#L1072-L1080

Comment: thx... i checked that and changed the line to:
                    <t t-foreach="categories" t-as="c">
  <option t-att-value="c.name" t-att-selected="c.name==quote_line.supplier"><t t-esc="c.name"/></option>
 </t>

works like a charm now....